How does Solana chain analyze the pool size?
How does the sol chain analyze the pool size?
Such as this

I can get the pool address through Jupiter's interface. The question is how to parse the pool size?

To calculate the Total Value Locked (TVL) or pool size on platforms like Raydium or Orca, you can check the token balances in their respective liquidity pool accounts. However, the Solana chain itself does not compute or track these values, and neither does Jupiter.
Jupiter, as a popular aggregator on Solana, focuses on routing trades and consolidating liquidity from various DEXs to provide the best prices. It does not calculate TVL for individual pools. These calculations are typically done and provided by the respective DEX platforms, such as Raydium, Orca, Serum, or Aldrin.
